# How to implement lazy loading on pages with Dart

Tags: dart, polymer, lazy-loading

I'm developing a Dart application where I would like to implement **lazy loading on libraries and pages**.

For instance, I have three pages/views: login, main_view and new_item. As far as I know, all of the application's code is being loaded at the same time if no lazy loading is implemented.

What I want to do is to load just the pages (or elements) that will be used by the application at that time and, when some other page/view is called, a "loading" message appears at the center of the screen, pretty much like what happens on Google Music (turning dice).

EDIT: I'm using bwu_polymer_routing for routing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use deferred loading of libraries http://news.dartlang.org/2014/08/dart-16-adds-support-for-deferred.html?m=1

Comment: Gunter, thanks for the reply, but I still don't understand how I will load pages and elements on demand, because I'm used to create pages separately and route them with bwu_polymer_routing. So the pages are not libraries, but polymer-elements, which I would like to load only when the user asks for it.

Comment: Sorry Felipe, I didn't look who was asking and the question doesn't have a dart-polymer tag. Polymer currently doesn't support lazy loading. There is an open issue to support it but I doubt this will be implemented in the current Polymer version and I assume it will take some time until this will be supported in the upcoming Polymer 1.0 port.

Comment: Günter, there's no problem. I forgot to point that I was using bwu_polymer_routing for that. So there's no way to build an application (that uses any Polymer elements) that gets loaded "on demand" (lazy loading) at this time, right? And what about using another routing package?

Comment: It's not about the routing package, Polymer elements can't be loaded lazily.

Comment: I understand. But suppose I won't use any Polymer elements in the application, do you have any idea on how I could implement lazy loading on pages?

Comment: You can load the HTML from the server on demand and add it to the page using Dart code (appendHtml, innerHtml, ...) and the code like shown in the site linked to in my answer. The routing package doesn't provide integrated support for this. You might want to create a custom view-port component that supports this.